# Using JavaScript to Build Remotely-Hosted Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, requirejs

We're developing an JavaScript application that will be hosted on our customer's server. We don't have access to the customer's server, and more-so it would be frowned-upon to send regular updates to the application. In order to provide regular maintenance, it's been proposed that the application that sits on the customer's server is nothing more than a single HTML file that consists of two lines: the doctype and a JavaScript include who's source links back to our server.

From here, the single JavaScript include would build the entire application, pulling in additional resources as necessary. It would start by building out the core HTML (based largely on the [HTML Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)), including appending tags for meta, style sheets, HTML, etc. Once the HTML page is flushed out, it would pull in the content the learner is seeking.

**Update Due to Comment**
The application needs to reside on the customers's server because there is a lot of communication between this application and other applications on the customer's server (in parent frames). If hosted on our server, it would be blocked due to browser security. There are options to get around this, but by having it on the customer's server, it removed a point of failure that is a common issue for similar applications.

Is there a better way to retain the ability to provide updates to the application without going through the customer?

Comment: If you're thinking of having the application on your own server with a skeleton page hosted on the customers machine, why not simply point them to a url instead? What is the reason for the necessity of putting "something" on the customers machine?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. There is a lot of communication between this application and other applications on the customer's server (in parent frames). This would be blocked due to browser security. There are options to get around this, but by having it on the customer's server, it removed a point of failure that is a common issue for similar applications attempting to do the same.

Comment: just host the javascript part , it should be no problem updating the application from your side. You dont even need an iframe or whatever , nor modify the html of your client page. you just need a script tag to include whatever functions you need. Even better get the customer proxy your jsscript.

Answer (score 0):

Per this question : ***Is there a better way to retain the ability to provide updates to the application without going through the customer?***

Could you not create a webservice on your server that provides JSON to the client's (Client being the other company, not an end user ) side that constructs whatever objects you need? That way you can update your webservice "whenever" and as long as you build the constructing js extensible enough, you can just pass object specifications to it remotely

Comment: The customer's API is built in JavaScript, so their server cannot access our data through a webservice. Our JavaScript application displays content to the user, who interacts with it, then the results are sent to the customer's API.

Comment: why not? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

You can receive webservice data in a crossdomain nature via JSONP

edit: it is important that you digest and fully consider the security concerns this approach can have.

Comment: The customer's API isn't setup to use JSONP, as it follows an industry specification for the data that is transferred. What would be required is an intermediary application on the customer's server that would interpret the JSONP requests and translate them to the specification's API (which is what our application would do).

Comment: Ahh yeah i feared it wouldn't be that easy. I guess my initial answer is @ face value how i would approach your question asked. I understand proprietary systems and the NDA related to them so I think the best answer I can give without getting a much greater understanding of the applications you are trying to string together I already have provided.... Good luck sir!

Answer (score 0):

If your application is pure JavaScript, your solution is fine.
And if you model well your application, you can make it updatable without going through your customer.
A simple proof of concept of a mock-up I built (a begining of an online JavaScript Desktop):
http://ilyeskooli.com/desktop/

If you check the page source, it's only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JDesktop/css/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JDesktop/css/JDesktop.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JDesktop/jdesktop.php"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
        <title>jDesktop</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the direction we're headed, but wasn't sure if we were crazy to build an web application entirely out of JavaScript. The challenge is that all of the lines in your example need to be reduced down to one line (a single script tag), and the doctype. At which time, not defining the basic tags (HTML, HEAD, etc.) works fine on modern browsers, but we weren't sure what trouble we'd get into on IE7/8.

Comment: Is not that crazy to build an application entirely out of JavaScript.
As you can notice:
<script type="text/javascript" src="JDesktop/jdesktop.php"></script>
is a PHP Script that compile my JS Classes into one JS file.